# Kotlin - How to save data from firebase to livedata with data class?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata

I trying run this code, but I get error: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String
i need to fetch data from realtime database and save it to livedata.

```
fun loadRecentlyAddedVoices(){
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_STICKERS).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
        ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            for (ds in snapshot.children) {
                recentlyAddedVoices.value = ds.getValue(VoicesModel::class.java).toString()
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }

    })
}
```

Voices Model:

```
data class VoicesModel(
       val title:String,
       val description: String,
       val count: Int,
       val likes: Int,
       val downloads: Int,
       val data: VoiceDataModel
)
```

VoiceDataModel:

```
data class VoiceDataModel(
       val voice_title: String,
       val source: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.String

According to your shared code, this exception is most probably given from the below:

```
recentlyAddedVoices.value = ds.getValue(VoicesModel::class.java).toString()
```

`recentlyAddedVoices` looks like the `MutableLiveData` object of a list of `VoiceDataModel`.

Using `toString()` here is the reason of the raised exception. And there is no reason to convert this value to a String.

Instead you need to create a normal list of `VoicesModel` first by iterating over the children of the datasnapshot, and then set the `LiveData` upon the completion of the list:

```
fun loadRecentlyAddedVoices(){
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_STICKERS).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
        ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            val temp: MutableList<VoicesModel> = mutableListOf()

            for (ds in snapshot.children) {
                 val value: voiceModel = ds.getValue<VoicesModel>(VoicesModel::class.java)
                 // Aggregating to a non-live data list
                 temp.add(value)
            }

            // Setting the Live data value:
            recentlyAddedVoices.value = temp
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }

    })
}
```